# UK Visit Visa is Sponsor's bank statement mandatory, provided they are not financial sponsor?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-of-funds, application-status

Me and my wife applied for UK Standard Tourism visa. we planning for short holiday of about 1 week. We are all self funded financially. However, One of Our son's is in UK upon evaluating the Application form at VFS desk during Bio-metrics,the staff  advised to also submit the son's Invitation letter as his details were mentioned in Visa form (I thought this is not needed as we going on holiday self funded. Have no plans to stay with son neither he is our financial sponsor).
He lives in Scotland and we plan to stay mostly in London. Yes we shall meet for some time but that's not the main purpose of visit TBH). However I asked my Son to email an Invitation letter immediately printed it out and submitted along with application & Bio metrics, along with his Passport and Bio-metric Id (he is on Tier 2 Sponsorship).

** everything happened so quickly. Now I am  concerned should I also have submitted his (son's) Bank statement & payslips. Can this visa be declined because I have not provided a complete overview of Son's Financial circumstances in UK. Anything I can do now ? **

Comment: As you are sponsoring yourself, might not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 9):

You are experiencing a condition called '*post-submission anxiety*', it's common for first-time applicants. They start to brood over their application, surf the net about it, and slowly work up to a full on flipping out.  There's naught to be done for post-submission anxiety; the only remedy is to brass it out.

On to the important point your question raises...

The VFS are couriers who have been trained in collecting biometrics.  What happens over the course of time is that some VFS employees take to mind that they are visa experts and start doing what you experienced: i.e., assessing people's applications and giving advice.  There have been serious and tragic outcomes from this causing unwarranted refusals. The UK government is aware of it and of course is working to stop it.

Based upon what you wrote, you should have ignored the VFS. Assuming that you listed your son as a family member...

[image]

[image]

There was no need for your son to invite you and write a letter of invitation, and certainly no need to include your son's financial details in your application.  His invitation letter is irrelevant and introduces an *unneeded layer of complexity* to the application.

Next time a VFS employee starts acting like a lawyer, you can tell him to get back to his station.  I.e., ignore it.

Comment: fully Agree ! Can anything be done now ? Most importantly is that enough to get a Rejection ?